# filering on level 2 of a multindex panda

Tags: python, dataframe, filtering

I have a 2 levels Dataframe

```
occupation     gender
administrator  F         0.455696
               M         0.544304
artist         F         0.464286
               M         0.535714
doctor         M         1.000000
educator       F         0.273684
               M         0.726316
engineer       F         0.029851
               M         0.970149
```

I would like to filer on level 2, meaning that I would like to filter on gender extracting all data regarding females.

My try was:

```
df.loc[(slice(None),"F"),:]
```

but it had no effect, meaning that it returned an unfiltered data frame showing both genders.

Any tips on how to do that?
Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a Series, not a data frame, try:

```
df.loc[(slice(None),"F")]
```

Or you can convert it to data frame and then use the data frame syntax:

```
df.to_frame().loc[(slice(None),"F"), :]
```

Comment: What a stupid I am!!! Thank you mate, it works perfectly. Of course the easier solution was to reset the index. But I feel it would be a waste of memory. Am I right? We should be able to operate directly on indexes instead of resetting and setting it again.

Comment: Definitely. If you don't need a data frame, the Series syntax would be a better way. The answer is trying to show the difference here.

Answer (score 0):

Apply reset_index() on the df and then slice

```
df = df.reset_index()
df[df['gender']== 'F']
```

Comment: Yes sure, this was the easy solution but I was looking for a solution acting directly on index because otherwise I feel that setting and resetting index all the time would be a waste of memory.  But I am not sure if it is correct what I am saying.

Comment: That's true. I usually reset_index as it comes in handy while plotting :)